# How can I assign value of .2f value of one variable to another variable?

Tags: java, variables

I want to assign a double value to another variable but only until it's first 2 decimal value.
Suppose I have 3.4586748547 value in a variable but I want to save 3.45 in another variable. How can I do this?
-I am using JAVA

Comment: which language are you using? For example in python the solution will be `round(3.4586748547, 2)`

Comment: I am using Java......Is there any way to do that in java? Also, I want to transfer the values using the variable name

Answer (score 1):

Using BigDecimal (`import java.math.BigDecimal;`):

```
BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(3.4586748547d));
double output = input.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).doubleValue();
System.out.println(output);
```

You can also use regex for that purpose, like below:

```
String inputString = String.valueOf(3.4586748547d);
String outputString = inputString.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d{2})\\d+", "$1");
System.out.println(outputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fixed point type in Java is `BigDecimal`.

Floating point is just an approximation, a sum of powers of 2. `3.45` or `3.4499999987` might be the exact same `double`. But one can round, and when printing with %.2f format will be shown nice. Though the error will be shown when summing or multiplying.

```
  x = Math.round(x * 100) / 100.0;
```

Unfortunately.